# How to create a file in Windows 8 system directories

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I am running Windows 8.1, Netbeans and Java 7. I have a jar file sitting in the dist directory, on the "C:" drive. (Netbeans automatically creates a "dist" directory to store the jar files it deploys.) When I run the jar and specify the "dist" as a target directory, my program is able to create files in "dist" using "createNewFile". (My program can also read from and write to the new created files).
My problem is that my program does not seem to be able to create files elsewhere on
the C: drive, under Windows 8.1 (It is able to do so under Windows XP.) To be more specific, createNewFile does not create a file, does not throw an exception, and a System.out.println ("Message") statement placed directly after the createNewFile statement does not execute. No errors are reported anywhere. I have tried to deactivate User Account Controls but no avail.

Does anyone know directories in Windows 8.1, outside of "dist", to which my program could
successively write files and this without having to call upon administrative privileges? Thank you.

Comment: Does relative paths work?

Comment: No. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.